# Which method of casting varchar to int is better sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got an import table with all columns coming in as `VARCHAR`.

One of the columns looks like this:

```
strSomeValue
------------
 1000.0000
 50000.0000
 4151.0000
```

And so on, and so on, always with the 4 decimal places of 0s.

I am casting this into an integer column and wanted to know what was the best way (most efficient).

I've got three so far:

```
CAST(CAST(strSomeValue as decimal(19,2)) as int)

CAST(SUBSTRING(strSomeValue , 1, CHARINDEX('.', strSomeValue ) - 1) AS INT)

CAST(ROUND(strSomeValue,0) as int)
```

so far I *think* that the 3rd method, using `ROUND`, is the best, based on my very limited knowledge of client statistics.

I was wondering if there is a better way, and what is the best way to determine quickly which query is faster? Is client statistics the only/best way, or are there better methods for analyzing simple things like this?

Comment: Actually, I would not think there is a huge difference between any of these in a real world application. I would use the one that is most readable/most stable. Aspects that could be important: Are you sure you always have a decimal point? Some European locale settings use a decimal comma!

Comment: Acutally you should ask a BA (Business Analyst) to confiurm that they ALWAYS are 4 digits and how to handle other scenarios regarding rounding. It may make a business difference.

Comment: why use round/floor ?what output you want ?why not simple cast(somevalue as int)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have numerical values - store them as **numbers** - not as `varchar` !

Comment: Originally I had in place an import system to save a Business Objects report as text and import it into my SQL Database through an upload interface.  In this Business Objects report, strSomeValue was always a 4-5 digit integer, or so it seemed.  When I setup my project and data tables, I used the INT data type.  Now, 9 months later, I have access to the Oracle DB behind Business Objects, and when I get data straight from there, it has 4 decimal places in my query results.  I checked the data type and it's "NUMBER".  I am fairly confident that the decimal places will be negligible.

Comment: Also, my import table was in varchar because the values coming in from the BO Report had symbols that could not implicitly convert to numerical format.  I am not about to restructure the entire database and ASP project and queries by switching from INT to DECIMAL

Comment: @KumarHarsh CAST('1000.0000' AS INT) receives an error in MS SQL

Comment: CAST('1000.0000' AS float) ?though wht kind different kind if value you will be getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the [Floor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) function to accomplish this.

```
SELECT FLOOR(strSomeValue)
```